# How to pass data between functional components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React we can pass data between class based components using states and props in the following manner:

**App.js**

```
import Name from './Name';
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "Tarun"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Name name={this.state.name}/>        
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Name.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Name extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                My name is : {this.props.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Name
```

But now since React has introduced functional components what is the equivalent code if I use functional components for both `App.js` and `Name.js`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) you could write something like this.

In `App`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {

  // `useState` returns an array with the state
  // and the method used to update the state
  // You can initialise the state with a variable/object
  const [name, setName] = useState('Tarun');

  // No need for a render method
  // Just return the JSX from the function
  return <Name name={name} />;
}
```

In `Name`:

```
import React from 'react'

// Props are passed down like normal function args
// Destructure `names` from the props object
export default function Name({ name }) {
  return <div>My name is: {name}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use **React v17+** with **TypeScript** & **functional components** in `React.StrictMode`, then:

**1) Parent to Child**

**1.1) Parent Component**, e.g. App.tsx

```
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
export default function App() {
  return <Dashboard title="My Dashboard"></Dashboard>;
}
```

**1.2) Child Component**, e.g. Dashboard

```
// src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.tsx

import React from "react";

type DashboardProps = {
  title: string;
};

const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = (props) => (
  <div>Dashboard Component {props.title}</div>
);

export default Dashboard;
```

This is the same as above (excerpt):

```
//..
export default function Dashboard(props: DashboardProps) {
  return <div>Dashboard Component {props.title}</div>;
}
```

**Lazy-Loading**

If you want to use **"Lazy-Loading"**, you have to change the Dashboard component slightly or maybe use a `Dashboard.lazy.tsx` like:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { DashboardProps } from '../../Types';
const LazyDashboard = lazy(() => import('./Dashboard'));

const Dashboard = (props: DashboardProps) => (
  <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <LazyDashboard {...props} />
  </Suspense>
);

export default Dashboard;
```

> I've moved the `DashboardProps` into a new file due to reusability.

```
// Types/index.tsx
export type DashboardProps = {
  title: string;
};
```

**2) Child to Parent (this time with React.useState hook)**

**2.1) Parent, e.g. App.tsx**

```
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
export default function App() {
  const [messageFromChild, getMessageFromChild] = React.useState(
    "Dad is waiting"
  );

  const sendDataToParent = (message: string) => {
    getMessageFromChild(message);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Dashboard
        props={{ title: "My Dear Dashboard" }}
        sendDataToParent={sendDataToParent}
      ></Dashboard>
      <div>
        <strong>From Child to Parent:</strong> {messageFromChild}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**2.2) Child, e.g. Dashboard.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { DashboardProps } from "../../Types";

const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = ({ props, sendDataToParent }) => (
  <div>
    <strong>From Parent to Child:</strong> {props.title}
    &nbsp;
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        sendDataToParent("Hi Dad");
      }}
    >
      Send to Parent
    </button>
  </div>
);

export default Dashboard;
```

**2.3) Types, e.g. Types/index.tsx**

```
export type DashboardProps = {
  props: {
    title: string;
  };
  sendDataToParent: (message: string) => void;
};
```

[image: Parent is waiting]
[image: Message from child]

Answer (score 5):

For `Name.jsx` you could do something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

// additionally you can do destructuring with props like this:
// const Name = ({name}) => {
const Name = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            My name is : {props.name}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Name;
```

Passing `props` happens at creation time of the functional component just like above. As the React documentation states:

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element. We call such components “function components” because they are literally JavaScript functions.

You can read further here: [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

For `App.jsx` let me suggest the following example:

```
import Name from './Name';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('Tarun');

    return (
        <Name name={name}/>        
    )
}

export default App;
```

From the above example `useState` function is the state hook what helps you create state object in your `App.jsx` functional component and for further updates you can use the `setName` function additionally for example on a click event. From the documentation:

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.

Please refer this link [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

I hope this helps!

Comment: How do I define state inside App function?

Comment: @TarunKhare Just updated my answer about states in function component. Let me know if something is not clear, thanks!

Comment: It is possible to pass data from a child(function component) to parent (class component)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useState` hook for state management in functional components as follows:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("Tarun");
    
    return (
        <div>
             <Name name={name}/>
        </div>
    );
}


//Name
export default function Name(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            My name is : {props.name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**App.js**

```
import Name from './Name';
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export function App(){
    const [name, setName] = "Tarun";
    return <Name name={name}>;
}
```

**Name.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export function Name({name}){
   return <div>My name is : {name} </div>
}
```

There you go.